# SVN with xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

How to use svn with xcode 4.6 ? Iam a newbie to SVN and i want to learn how to upload projects to trunk folder using svn any tutorials or please guide me in accomplishing this .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use SVN with xCode 4.6. Below are the steps how you can use svn to upload your app to trunk folder in svn.

1. Install command line tools. For that go to Preferences >> Downloads in your xCode.
2. Create project in SVN server. For example: IPH_MyProject
3. Open organizer from xCode
4. Go to Repositories tab
5. Add new Repository from bottom left corner using "+" button.
6. Add your project name and svn URL. For example: http_URL/svn/IPH_MyProject. Press next. It will ask your svn username and password. Add it and press ok.
7. Finish this process. You will get that project in left panel in project list in the same tab (Repositories tab of organizer).
8. Select "Root" folder for that project in the list.
9. Import all your project files including .xcodeproj file from your local copy to the trunk folder of that Root directory.
10. Checkout "Root" directory to your desired location.
11. Start developing the project in svn copy.

That's it..

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between the SVN client you are using and XCode. XCode offers a built-in (rather awful) SVN tool though it is advised to use any other client (SVNX is a good one).

You check out a working copy, make your changes and see all of this reflect in the SVNX.

Hope this helps shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response .What iam doing is i intalled mod_dav_svn in a server having cent-os after that i created a repository iam tryin upload my xcode project but its not uploading

Answer (score 0):

SmartSVN(http://www.smartsvn.com/) would be a good choice to use. The basics for SVN, have a look at this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPUdXvjY_G4

Hope this helps to start...